# How to use GETDATE() function in SQL Server to select a column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I use the `GETDATE()` function in SQL Server to calculate the date exactly one year prior to the day the query is executed? I want to use this value in a query.

E.g :

```
 Select LTRating, RHDate 
 from Accounts and If LTRating ='D' then RHDate = CURRENTDATE()-365
```

I wish to retrieve all `LTRating` column values where the `LTRating` value is 'D' and the Date is exactly one year ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186819.aspx) and access a date exactly ine year ago thus:

```
dateadd(yy, -1, getdate())
```

e.g.

```
select 
LTRating
, case when LTRating = 'D' then dateadd(yy, -1, getdate()) else RHDate end
from Accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use datediff function:

```
Select ...
from table
where datediff(Day, RHDate, getdate()) = 365
```

Comment: this is inaccurate, leap year has 366 while the rest are 365

Comment: True, I just wanted to show another function :)

Comment: then you could have just used `getdate() - 365 `, which has same problem leap year is 366

Answer (score 0):

```
select  LTRating, RHDate 
from Accounts 
where datediff (yy, RHDate, getdate()) = 1
```

by using `datediff` function can get difference in months and years

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable where RHDate = DATEADD(yy,-1,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select [LTRating], [RHDate] from [Accounts] 
where [LTRating] = 'D' AND [RHDate] >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Adding -1 to year of current date basically just inverts the function dateadd since there is no dateminus :)

Answer (score 0):

The following statement returns

- all `LTRating` that are not 'D'; and
- choose one of the following:

  - `LTRating` values that are 'D' and `RHDate` is **exactly** one year; OR
  - `LTRating` values that are 'D' and `RHDate` is **older than** one year; OR
  - `LTRating` values that are 'D' and `RHDate` is **younger** one year.

```sql
SELECT LTRating, RHDate 
FROM Accounts
WHERE ( LTRating != 'D'

  -- use this for exact comparison (including seconds!)
  OR RHDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())

  -- use this for RHDate older than one year
  OR RHDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())

  -- use this for RHDate younger than one year
  OR RHDate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())

);
```

Please bear in mind that DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME types include the time component (al least to the second), so, in most of the cases, datetime column comparisons are done using `>` or `<` operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select LTRating, RHDate 
from Accounts 
where LTRating <> 'D' 
OR (LTRating ='D' and RHDate = DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))
```